# Is it possible for a human to feel no emotion?

Tags: emotion

I have heard that there are some people who don't feel emotions. Is that really true? Is it really possible for someone to feel no emotions?

Comment: Any evidence to support your claim or is it just hearsay?

Comment: I think this question is different than the proposed duplicate.   Whether it's possible for a human to feel no emotions is an interesting theoretical question, independent of any empirical motivation for it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a physical possibility but you need, at the bare minimum, to feel for your self to survive; like the need to eat. If you don't want to call hunger and similar things for feelings it would be a problem anyway because discus is what make you avoiding eating bad or toxic food and fear to avid getting eaten etc.

scorce: http://atlasofemotions.org/#continents/disgust

What you most likely have heard is that psychopaths don't feel anything and that is not true. They do care abut them self and others in self interest but would not start crying for anyone from feeling empathy.  (I don't have a source for the later part but you can test it with a mind experiment with a psychopath and a smaller guy that tries to piss of the psychopath. Per definition the psychopath don't care if he kills the other dude but if he do he will end up in jail) http://www.dictionary.com/browse/psychopath

(Sorry for the horrible English, was a while since I last wrote anything)

Comment: Hi Alfons, welcome at CogSci. Thank you for sharing your view, but do you have any credible (scientific) sources that support your statements? Here at CogSci we aim to have verifiable answers, instead of opinions and/or discussions.

Comment: This is maybe an interesting answer, but fairly rudimentary.  It doesn't really define what an emotion is, without which you can't really answer this question.  If we reopen the question, the answer would be a conditional "yes".

Comment: I did search a bit to see if hunger whas defind as a fealing but that did depend on the area so I do think it is a ok answer for the question and it's probebly the second part that moste whant.